# Нужно решить задачу python

Tags: python, webbrowser

Мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователь вводил "что такое ......" , программа скопировала бы определение из Википедии, и вывела на экран.
При необходимости, можно использовать разные библиотеки и языки

Comment: Здесь не пункт решения задач по запросу. Нужно - делайте, возникнут вопросы - задавайте

Comment: Вопрос в том, как скопировать определние из Википедии и присвоить любой переменной.

Comment: Это вопрос из разряда "напишите код за меня", вы хоть что-то пробовали сами написать? Уж если вы хоть чуточку работали с вебом на питоне, то хотя вы хотя бы должны представлять, как работать с API сайтов или в крайнем случае как получить "голый" текст html страницы, а уже из нее достать необходимый текст, вот как найти определение в таком тексте - уже более-менее валидный вопрос, а так вы просто хотите, чтобы кто-то написал вам программу.

Comment: Я хотел узнать, как это вообще делается, ведь я раньше не работал с вебом на питоне

Comment: Тогда имхо вы взяли на себя слишком непосильную задачу и начать стоит с прочтения статей и, возможно, курсов, но никак не с "как мне написать код?".

Answer (score 1):

Ограничусь, пожалуй, общими рекомендациями по алгоритмике получения данных с Википедии.

1. делаешь `import requests` и `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.
2. Получаешь страницу через `requests.get()`.
3. Загоняешь ответ в `BeautifulSoup` и посредством `find()` находишь то что нужно.

P.S. Обрати внимание, что bs4 не входит в стандартный набор Python, её надо ставить отдельно через `pip`.

Comment: тогда можно сразу pip install wikipedia и дальше совсем не париться. Это же python :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe и такое есть??))) не знал.. спасибо, учту)) авось пригодится где